# How to get an array of strings using regex for ternary operator?

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex

There is a task to make a regular expression for a ternary operator without nesting. I'm stuck at this point. Help me please!

String for regex:

```
let str = "!(a == b) && (c == d) ? value1 : 'value2'"
```

The result of the script with regex:

```
let result = ["!(a == b) && (c == d)", "value1", "'value2'"]
```

The result is an array with strings. The line where the condition is a simple expression, without double question marks. Only logical operators.

I tried to do regex, but it didn't work.

Comment: Please don't ask the same question [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77173899/getting-an-array-of-strings-using-regex-for-ternary-operator) not even with a different account.

Comment: Regex isn't the best tool for parsing code. Consider creating a parser, or using one that's already been made?

Comment: If you can guarantee that the only `?` or `:` in the string are part of the ternary, `let result = str.split(/[:\?]/g)`.  Otherwise it's really hard and you need to use a parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
let str = "!(a == b) && (c == d) ? value1 : 'value2'";

let regex = /([^\?]+)\s+\?\s+(.+?)\s+:\s+(.+)/;
let result = str.match(regex).slice(1);

console.log(result);
```

Here is the result :

```
["!(a == b) && (c == d)", "value1", "'value2'"]
```